# Using Parse's JavaScript framework with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, parse-platform

I would like to use the Parse framework directly in Google Apps Script and copied the following [source code](https://parse.com/downloads/javascript/parse/latest/js) from Parse.com directly into my project.

However, it seems that there are some adjustments required to get this to work correctly. e.g. when running the following sample code...

```
function upload()
{
  Parse.initialize("wCxiu8kyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy", "bTxxxxx8bxxxxxxxxx");
  var TestObject = Parse.Object.extend("TestObjectJSSSSS");
  var testObject = new TestObject();
  testObject.save({foo: "bar"}, {
     success: function(object) {
     alert("yay! it worked");
  }
  });
}
```

… I get the error message `TypeError: Cannot call method "getItem" of undefined`.

which seems to relate to `localStorage`. I believe I should replace `localStorage` with a similar storage type available in Google Apps Script. Would that be possible and how would I need to adjust the Parse code?

What other adjustments would I need to get to the Parse framework to work in my Google Apps Script project?

Comment: How did you get your code working? Did you use REST API as suggested? Can you provide links to documentation or examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that using Parse REST API would be a far simpler solution and it is meant for such cases.